# nginx ssl error, no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking

Tags: nginx, centos, ssl, centos7

when i add comodo ssl to nginx server on centos 7 i got this error

```
6925#0: *1045 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: 2.89.238.146, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

2019/04/30 16:47:08 [error] 6925#0: *1046 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: 156.196.125.24, server: 0.0.0.0:443

my config file is

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen 443  default_server ssl;
    server_name s1c.govid.co;
    root         /var/www/html;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

 server {
```

====================

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
   listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
   server_name  s1c.govid.co;
    ssl on;

   root         /var/www/html;

    ssl_certificate "/ssl/govid.co.crt";
    ssl_certificate_key "/ssl/govid.co. server {
   listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name  s1c.govid.co;
    ssl on;

   root         /var/www/html;

   ssl_certificate "/ssl/govid.co.crt";
    ssl_certificate_key "/ssl/govid.co.key";
   ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
   ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    ssl_ciphers         EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH;
     ssl_protocols       TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;key";
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
```

Comment: Put the `ssl_certificate` in.

Comment: Your config does not make much sense. If you one `server` section for port 80 and 443 ssl and then another one for port 443 ssl but for the same `server_name`. The first one has no `ssl_certificate` while the second has. The second one also looks corrupted, maybe you did not properly copy+paste stuff into the question.